# Batch file to send data to com port

Tags: windows, batch-file, serial-port

I ordered this "cash drawer opener" its connected via usb to your pc. Now i want it to open my cash drawer. For this i have to send a character to the com port as described in the operation manual:

[Operation Manual](https://gyazo.com/bdea0d6b1eb118be52dd472f98c01f3d)

So I want to accomplish this task via .bat file but i'm completely new to this and I have no idea how to do it.

I only found this solution for the powershell:

```
    PS> [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
COM3
PS> $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
PS> $port.open()
PS> $port.WriteLine("Hello world")
PS> $port.Close()
```

Can anyone help  me to solve this?

EDIT: It would also be possible if I open a powershell script. How can i turn the above powershell code in a powershell script?

Comment: the bad news is you're not going to win using batch. to make a powershell script save your code ito a text file and give it a `.ps1` extension.

Comment: But do I not have to change anything for the ps1 file? Just line for line without the PS> ?

Comment: a script in powershell is essentially just batches of commands. so yes, just add each command as you ran it, and that should work

Comment: @GerhardBarnard, what do you mean by not going to win?  People have been doing this with batch files for decades. Sending data to a com port is no different then writing to a file in a batch file.  It is simple redirection with the `>` character and use the `MODE` command to setup the connection parameters.

Comment: @Squashman, I am aware, what I mean is there are complications when using batch. Powershell is the new batch so rather use it.